# Stochastic Gradient Descent - Least Squares

Tags: regression, python, least-squares, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient-descent

I am not sure if I implemented the SGD in a proper way since in calculations it gives way to big error even on the training set. Can you help me to figure out where I made a mistake?
Here $D$ is the input data each row of which is a single observation with its features.
$y$ is the target data.
$W$ is the weight matrix.

The loss function is $1/2\|DW - y\|^2$

````
# gradient is computed as D^T(DW - y) 
def grad(D, W, y):
    x = np.dot(D, W) - y
    return np.dot(D.T, x)

def least_squares_SGD(D, y, a = 0.1, n_iter = 1000):
    n, d = D.shape
    indx = random.sample(range(n), d)
    
    # Heuristic initialization of the weight matrix $W$ by choosing at random $d$ observations
    # and computing WX = Y, W = X^{-1}Y.
    X = [D[i] for i in indx]
    Y = [y[i] for i in indx]
    W = np.dot(np.linalg.inv(X), Y)
    
    for _ in range(n_iter):
        W = W - a*grad(D, W, y)
    return W

def eval_least_squares_SGD(W, test_x, test_y):
    y_hat = np.dot(W, test_x.T)
    return np.sum((test_y-y_hat)**2)
```
````